# NSObject can not access property and method

Tags: objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I have a very strange problem, I have two classes the first one is a sub class of NSObject class it contains a method that add an object to its array. See the code below:

```
    #import "portfolio.h"

    @implementation portfolio


    -(void) addStockObject:(stockHolding *)stock
    {
        [self.stocks addObject:stock ];
    }

    +(portfolio *) alloc
    {
        return [self.superclass alloc];
    }

    -(portfolio *) init
    {
        self.stocks=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        return self;
    }

    -(NSString *)getCurrentValue
    {

        stockHolding *stockInArray;
        float currentValue=0.0;

        for (NSInteger *i=0; i<[self.stocks count]; i++) {
            stockInArray = [self.stocks objectAtIndex:i];
            currentValue+=stockInArray.currentValue;

        }
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Current Value: %f",currentValue];
    }
    @end
```

so when i call the method -(void) addStockObject:(stockHolding *)stock, i get the following error(during runtime):

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
    reason: '-[NSObject addStockObject:]: unrecognized selector 
    sent to instance 0x8b48d90'
```

The calling code is:

```
     p=[[portfolio alloc]init];
     [p addStockObject:s];
     portfolio *p;
```

anyone can tell me what is wrong?

the other class has a property and it seems that it can not access it during compile time.
I'm really confused.

Thank you,
missa

Comment: Please follow naming conventions and start classes with a capital letter.  For example, your `portfolio` class should be `Portfolio`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, never override `+(portfolio *) alloc`.

Second, init methods must call another init method and you must always check `self` for `nil` before setting ivars. Apple recommends against using properties to set ivars in init methods and init methods should always return `instancetype` in compilers that support it or `id` in those that don't.

```
-(instancetype) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _stocks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Calling `init` for a direct subclass of `NSObject` shouldn't be technically necessary, just a good habit.  Getting rid of `alloc`, however, is key.

Comment: Hmm, I never heard that it's not necessary for direct subclasses. Have a reference for that off-hand? Like you said, either way it's a good habit.

Comment: From `NSObject` docs: "The init method defined in the NSObject class does no initialization; it simply returns self."

Comment: @PhillipMills I would say that you should always call `[super init]` for 2 reasons. 1) You may change a class' base class. 2) Someday maybe `NSObject` will do something in `init`.

Comment: Thank you very much i got rid off alloc and it works perfectly.